# A project using two projects with Netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, project

I am using Netbeans 7.4. I have three projects:

- [1] one for login
- [2] one to read the content of an xml file using jsf without a database
- [3] one to show and use a database using hibernate

Can I make one big project with Netbeans 7.4?  The project [1] will use the project [2] and [3].

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short: **Yes!**

Right click onto your *1st project* **`Properties -> Libraries -> Add Project…`** add your *both projects* there.